# How to store URL from BeautifulSoup results to a list and then to a table

Tags: python, pandas, url, beautifulsoup

I'm **scraping** a real estate webpage trying to get some URLs to then create a table.
https://www.zonaprop.com.ar/locales-comerciales-alquiler-palermo-hollywood-0-ambientes-publicado-hace-menos-de-1-mes.html
I have days triying to

1. store the results to a list or dictionary to then
2. create a table
   but I'm really stuck

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
source=requests.get('https://www.zonaprop.com.ar/locales-comerciales-alquiler-palermo-hollywood-0-ambientes-publicado-hace-menos-de-1-mes.html').text
soup=BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')


#Extract URL 
link_text = ''
URL=[]
PlacesDf = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Address', 'Location.lat', 'Location.lon'])
for a in soup.find_all('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("/propiedades/")}):
  link_text = a['href']
  URL='https://www.zonaprop.com.ar'+link_text
  print(URL)
```

ok, the output It's ok for me:

```
https://www.zonaprop.com.ar/propiedades/local-en-alquiler-soler-6000-palermo-hollywood-a-44227001.html#map
https://www.zonaprop.com.ar/propiedades/local-en-alquiler-soler-6000-palermo-hollywood-a-44227001.html
https://www.zonaprop.com.ar/propiedades/local-en-alquiler-soler-6000-palermo-hollywood-a-44227001.html
https://www.zonaprop.com.ar/propiedades/excelente-esquina-en-alquiler-s-lote-propio-con-43776599.html
https://www.zonaprop.com.ar/propiedades/excelente-esquina-en-alquiler-s-lote-propio-con-43776599.html
https://www.zonaprop.com.ar/propiedades/excelente-esquina-en-alquiler-s-lote-propio-con-43776599.html
https://www.zonaprop.com.ar/propiedades/excelente-local-en-alquiler-palermo-hollywood-fitz-44505027.html#map
https://www.zonaprop.com.ar/propiedades/excelente-local-en-alquiler-palermo-hollywood-fitz-44505027.html
https://www.zonaprop.com.ar/propiedades/excelente-local-en-alquiler-palermo-hollywood-fitz-44505027.html
https://www.zonaprop.com.ar/propiedades/local-palermo-hollywood-44550855.html#map
https://www.zonaprop.com.ar/propiedades/local-palermo-hollywood-44550855.html
https://www.zonaprop.com.ar/propiedades/local-palermo-hollywood-44550855.html
https://www.zonaprop.com.ar/propiedades/local-comercial-o-edificio-corporativo-oficinas-500-43164952.html
https://www.zonaprop.com.ar/propiedades/local-comercial-o-edificio-corporativo-oficinas-500-43164952.html
https://www.zonaprop.com.ar/propiedades/local-comercial-o-edificio-corporativo-oficinas-500-43164952.html
https://www.zonaprop.com.ar/propiedades/local-palermo-viejo-44622843.html#map
https://www.zonaprop.com.ar/propiedades/local-palermo-viejo-44622843.html
https://www.zonaprop.com.ar/propiedades/local-palermo-viejo-44622843.html
https://www.zonaprop.com.ar/propiedades/alquiler-de-local-comercial-en-palermo-hollywood-44571635.html#map
https://www.zonaprop.com.ar/propiedades/alquiler-de-local-comercial-en-palermo-hollywood-44571635.html
https://www.zonaprop.com.ar/propiedades/alquiler-de-local-comercial-en-palermo-hollywood-44571635.html
```

the thing is that the output are real links(you can click on them and go to the page)

But when I try to store it in a new variable(list or dictionary with the column name 'Address' to join with "PlacesDf"(same column name 'Address')) /convert to table/ or whatever trick I cannot find the solution. In fact, when I try to convert to pandas:

```
Address = pd.dataframe(URL)
```

it only creates a one row table.

I expect to see something like that

```
Adresses=['https://www.zonaprop.com.ar/propiedades/local-en-alquiler-soler-6000-palermo-hollywood-a-44227001.html#map','
https://www.zonaprop.com.ar/propiedades/local-en-alquiler-soler-6000-palermo-hollywood-a-44227001.html',...]
```

or a Dictionary or whatever I can turn to a table with pandas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should do the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
import pandas as pd


source=requests.get('https://www.zonaprop.com.ar/locales-comerciales-alquiler-palermo-hollywood-0-ambientes-publicado-hace-menos-de-1-mes.html').text
soup=BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')

#Extract URL
all_url = [] 
link_text = ''
PlacesDf = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Address', 'Location.lat', 'Location.lon'])
for a in soup.find_all('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("/propiedades/")}):
  link_text = a['href']
  URL='https://www.zonaprop.com.ar'+link_text
  print(URL)
  all_url.append(URL)

df = pd.DataFrame({"URLs":all_url}) #replace "URLs" with your desired column name
```

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, it was very useful, I have one question, there's a row size limit? because the URL appears incomplete?

Comment: @johnGuarenas yes you can increase the column width with the following line `pd.set_option('max_colwidth',-1000)`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you are getting lat and lon from and I am making an assumption about address. I can see you have a lot of duplicates in your current urls returns. I would suggest the following css selectors to target just the listings links. These are class selectors so faster than your current method.

Use the len of that returned list of links to define the row dimension and you already have the columns.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import pandas as pd
import re

r = requests.get('https://www.zonaprop.com.ar/locales-comerciales-alquiler-palermo-hollywood-0-ambientes-publicado-hace-menos-de-1-mes.html')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml') #'html.parser'
links = ['https://www.zonaprop.com.ar' + item['href'] for item in soup.select('.aviso-data-title a')]
locations = [re.sub('\n|\t','',item.text).strip() for item in soup.select('.aviso-data-location')]
df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(len(links)),columns= ['Address', 'Lat', 'Lon', 'Link'])
df.Link = links
df.Address = locations
print(df)
```